# Git push issue and pull issue

Tags: git-push, git-pull

I have created a bare repo (`/Volumes/500gb/myproject.git`).

I have added the bare repo to my working directory `/Volumes/500gb/test1`.

I have created the branches as follows:

```
# git branch
  master
  test1
* test2
```

I have created a file in branch `test2` and committed.

1. when I try to push to `test2` branch, I am getting the following errors:

   ```
   # git push origin master
   To /Volumes/500gb/myproject.git
   ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
   error: failed to push some refs to '/Volumes/500gb/myproject.git'
   hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
   hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
   hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
   ```
2. When I try to pull from `master`, I am getting following errors. But I could merge the `test2` branch from `master`.

   ```
   # git pull master
   fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   ```

Someone, please clarify the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Part of) the syntax for git pull is `git pull <repository> <refspec>`.

In your case, when you call `git pull master`, git thinks you want to pull the current branch state from a repository named `master`.

So instead, just type `git pull` if you're on master, or `git pull origin master` to be more precise.

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Your first question should be easier to solve once you can pull and update your local repository state.